# GraphX : How to fetch all edges with a given label

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Graph with millions of edges where edges are represented by `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[String]] = MappedRDD[4]` . I have two questions :

1)How can I fetch all the nodes with a given edge label

2) Is it possible to create indexes on the RDDs or a specific column of the RDD to make the look up faster?

Please excuse me for the triviality of the question, I am new to the language and its taking me sometime to get used to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Cant you just .filter(_._2=="label") on the rdd?

2) I think what youre looking for is [IndexedRDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/1297), but I think you need to rebuild spark from the latest source